# Python 3: KeyError 0 when using dataframe's dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Using the below code I am trying to insert n-DataFrames to an MSSQL table.

```
for file in os.listdir():
   print('# Inserting ' + file + ' . . .')
   df = pd.read_csv(file)
   df = df.fillna('NULL')
   if(len(df)>1):
       dfs = partDF(df , lim)
       for k in dfs.keys():
           print('\t' + str(int(k.split('t')[1])+1) + ' / ' + str(len(dfs.keys()))+ '\t')
           aux = dfs[k]
           insert2SQL(aux, table)
           del(aux)
       print(' OK :)')
   del(df, dfs)
```

The `partDF()` function splits the dataframe into smaller ones so that each one doesn't exceed 1000 rows length. These dataframes are returned inside a dictionary, whose keys are named t0, t1, t1 ... tn.
Note that for security, I used the key names directly from `dict.keys()` method.

The above code raises **Keyerror 0** after it inserts the first dataframe inside the loop.

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0e1d02aa1939> in <module>()
      8                         print('\t' + str(int(k.split('t')[1])+1) + ' / ' + str(len(dfs.keys()))+ '\t')
      9                         aux = dfs[k]
---> 10                         insert2SQL(aux, table)
     11                         del(aux)
     12                 print(' OK :)')

<ipython-input-2-fd6c30d5a003> in insert2SQL(tablilla, sqlTab)
     27         vals = list()
     28         for field in tablilla.columns:
---> 29                 if(type(tablilla[field][0]) == str):
     30                         vals.append(True)
     31                 else:

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    621         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    622         try:
--> 623             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    624 
    625             if not is_scalar(result):

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   2558         try:
   2559             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2560                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2561         except KeyError as e1:
   2562             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

However, when I execute the below code where I am just printing the dataframes' headers, no such error is encountered:

```
for file in os.listdir():
   df = pd.read_csv(file)
   df = df.fillna('NULL')
   if(len(df)>1):
       dfs = partDF(df , lim)
       for k in dfs.keys():
           aux = dfs[k]
           print('\t\t\t\tOriginal length : ' + str(len(aux)))
           print(aux.head(10))
           #insert2SQL(aux, table)
           del(aux)
   del(df, dfs)
```

I don't understand what is happening and would be glad if someone could help me.

PS. I didn't post the `partDF()` code because I think it is very clear from the 2 code snippets that it's not the reason for the error.

PS2. insert2SQL code:

```
def insert2SQL(tablilla, sqlTab):
    # connection data
    # servName = 'server'
    # userName = 'me'
    # psswd = 'pass'
    # cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server=servName, UID=userName, PWD=psswd)
    # cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    rows = len(tablilla)
    fields = tablilla.columns
    vals = list()
    for field in tablilla.columns:
        if(type(tablilla[field][0]) == str):
            vals.append(True)
        else:
            vals.append(False)

    textFields = dict(zip(fields, vals))
    q = "INSERT INTO " + sqlTab + " VALUES ("

    for r in range(rows):
        for field in fields:
            if(str(tablilla.loc[r, field]) != 'NULL'):
                quot = "'" if textFields[field] else ""
            else:
                quot = ""
            q += quot + str(tablilla.loc[r, field]) + quot + ", "
        q = q[0:len(q)-2] + '),('  
    q = q[0:len(q)-2]

    print(q)
    print('\n')
    # cursor.execute(q)
    # cursor.commit()
    # cnxn.close()
```

EDITTED:

After the remarks you made me, I tried to review over your comments and found my error is because I always try to compare the first row for each dataframe, forgetting that  after splitting the big dataframes pandas keeps the index rows. The solution was just applying df.reset_index() to each dataframe I send to my insert2SQL() function.

Thanks alot!

PS. Is there a way to vote up your comments as long they were useful to me?
How do I close this question?

Comment: Can you add the error stack trace? At what line did the error occurred?

Comment: You should always include the complete Traceback in your question if there is one.  Copy it and paste it into the question - formatted as code.

Comment: If your loop runs fine by substituting `print(...` for the call to `insert2SQL` then the problem must be in that function. Please take the time to read [mcve].

Comment: The Traceback is showing you that `---> 29                 if(type(tablilla[field][0]) == str):` in `insert2SQL` is causing the error. You haven't provided enough info. You'll need to do a little more digging then come back with a better question.

Comment: @wwii just added the insert2SQL code as the PS2. I've commented the pyodbc parts, so it just creates the insert statments. Sorry for my dirty code :(

Comment: I'm trying to get it. Should I use df.dtypes for the column to compare is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Is table initialized somewhere? You need to initialize it.

UPDATE: In the function insert check if the followings actually exist every time the loop iterates?
- tablilla[field][0]
- textFields[field]
- tablilla.loc[r, field]

I suggest you comment out each for loop one by one and see what part causes the error.

Comment: Yes.
table, lim are initialized before this loop.

Comment: What is the function insert2SQL? Looks like you are trying to add a thing to something like a dict or list that is not initialized.

Comment: insert2SQL receives a Dataframe and a string (aux, table_name) and creates an insert statment with the Dataframe values to the table that table_name gives. In this case, the table is always the same. Want to see the function?

Comment: yep this might be helpful